# pg_close() error? is a sub close closing the 2 connections?

Tags: php

I am currently getting this error: `pg_close(): 12 is not a valid PostgreSQL link resource`. This is the code that is being executed:

```
    function getProyectosDeUsuarioDAO($idUsuario)
{
    $conexion = conectar();
    $consulta = "sql things here;";
    $resultado = pg_query($consulta) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . pg_last_error());
    $lista = array();

    $lista = pg_fetch_all($resultado);
    var_dump($lista);
    $listaProyectos = array();
    if(!empty ($lista))
    {
        foreach ($lista as $p)
        {

            $proyecto = new Proyecto();

            $proyecto->setNombre($p['nombre']);
            $proyecto->setFechaInicio($p['fechainicio']);
            $proyecto->setFechaFin($p['fechafin']);
            $proyecto->setId($p['id']);
            //Cargar roles del usuario para cada proyecto
            $proyecto->setRoles(getRolesByProyecto($proyecto->getId(),$idUsuario));

            array_push($listaProyectos, $proyecto) ;
        }

        if($conexion)
        {
             pg_close($conexion); //##############error here#################
        }
        pg_free_result($resultado);
        var_dump($listaProyectos);  
        return $listaProyectos;
    }
```

`var_dumps` are made to check if the query is working and it does work; I am not sure how to debug this.

I am using `php_pgsql` and WAMP server
`($conexion)` works for checking, however I'm not sure if connection is live or not?

Comment: Your `conexion` variable is set by the `conectar()` function, which you have not shown. It is otherwise not used. I'd say the problem is with `conectar()`. Maybe you're returning a file descriptor ID by accident?

Comment: conectar() works, i use that function on my others querrys, and on this function the result is ok, $listaProyectos is loaded whit the correct data

Comment: PHP allows you to use default database descriptors.  Perhaps your problem is not with pg_close but with pg_query using the wrong db connection?